# SQL Sumif functions / GROUP BY & SUM?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, sumifs

I have been stuck on this for a while now and cannot for the life of me understand why the SQL is not pulling through what I want. It seems simple and I know it's simple but I can't get the right numbers.

I have some code to pull data from joined tables on our database showing customer numbers, products purchased, date purchased along with product price and quantity of that product line. When I set between dates and GROUP by date, it works perfectly and pulls through all the right info.

What I want is to GROUP by product, summing the quantity of products purchased within a date range for each customer. When I try to sum(SIL.ILQTY) the sum over calcualtes this value.......I have tried Sum with CASE which also fails. I have the code below and have filter the records to make testing easier so only shows one product and one customer with 7 purchase dates for that product.

The following code shows records by date which works:

```
SELECT SIH.SICUST, SIL.ILPROD, date(SIL.ILDATE), SIL.ILNET, SIL.ILQTY,
       SIL.ILQTY*SIL.ILNET, SIH.SICUST || ' ' ||  rtrim(SIL.ILPROD) || ' '
FROM NWBAKERS.BPCSF.IIM IIM,
     NWBAKERS.BPCSF.SIH SIH,
     NWBAKERS.BPCSF.SIL SIL
WHERE SIH.SIINVN = SIL.ILINVN
  AND IIM.IPROD = SIL.ILPROD
  AND ((date(SIL.ILDATE) between '02/01/2016' and '02/29/2016'))
  and SIL.ILWHS ='PR'
  and SIL.ILQTY > '0'
  and SIH.SICUST = '40634'
  and SIL.ILPROD = '81039'
GROUP BY SIH.SICUST, SIL.ILPROD, date(SIL.ILDATE), SIL.ILQTY, SIL.ILNET
```

The problem is when I remove the date(SIL.ILDATE) from the group by statement and sum(SIL.ILQTY) in the select statement in order to get the Unique customer number which purchased the total number of unique products(ILQTY) in the date range specified.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please????

Sample Data Image for above:

[image]

Data with Date removed from Group by and sum(ILQTY) in select statement:

[image: image2]

[Desired result for one product by customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYSlr.png)

[Image shows the added fields for invoice number and order number, giving duplicate lines for date/quantity/invoice as order number are different. The sum of these qty values is what my SQL code was summing previously.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6M5i.png)

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag because the syntax is clearly not SQL Server.

Comment: Move most of it (date/trim/etc) into a derived table, perform the group by at the main level.

Comment: show an example of the data, the desired output and the incorrect output you're getting.

Comment: Just to make sure... if you remove date(SIL.ILDATE) from the group by statement you have to remove it from the SELECT list as well. If you sum(SIL.ILQTY) in the select statement you have to remove it from the GROUP BY as well

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have seen that there can be several orders under one invoice number which generates duplicate values for QTY on the same date. This is why my sum function fails (the way I want it) and overcounts the number of Products.......Would I need to join differently? I added the data I get first, what I want, and where it is incorrect after removing date in group and using sum(ILQTY)

Comment: Not your actual problem, but: 1) Don't use `BETWEEN`, especially with date/time/timestamp types - use lower-bound inclusive (`>=`) upper-bound exclusive (`<`) ranges.  For one thing, that would allow you to specify it as a full timestamp, and avoid the need to cast to `DATE`, which is making the condition non-SARGable.  2) Use ISO formatting for dates (`yyyy-mm-dd`), because otherwise the value returned is ambiguous.  3) Explicitly list joins, don't use the comma-separated `FROM` syntax.  We're still waiting on starting data and desired output.

Comment: OK, I've added 2 other images now, one shows the desired result of one product ine per customer summing the QTY. The next shows the added fields of Invoice Number and order number which seems to be the reason for the duplications.....each order on the same day looks to to use the same QTY for each product whether or not that product was ordered again. I think the second shows the starting data you may need to see......Thanks for taking the time to look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get this to work, was a bit different than I thought but it works well and return perfect information......Thanks to Everyone who tried to help with this Question!

```
SELECT T.SICUST, T.ILPROD, SUM(Quantity) as Num_Products 
FROM
(
SELECT SIH.SICUST, SIL.ILPROD, SIL.ILNET, MAX(SIL.ILQTY) as Quantity
FROM NWBAKERS.BPCSF.IIM IIM,
     NWBAKERS.BPCSF.SIH SIH,
     NWBAKERS.BPCSF.SIL SIL
WHERE SIH.SIINVN = SIL.ILINVN
AND IIM.IPROD = SIL.ILPROD
AND ((date(SIL.ILDATE) between '02/01/2016' and '02/29/2016'))
and SIL.ILWHS ='PR'
and SIL.ILQTY > '0'
and SIH.SICUST = '40634'
and SIL.ILPROD = '81039'
GROUP BY SIH.SICUST, SIL.ILPROD, SIL.ILNET, SIL.ILINVN
) AS T
GROUP BY T.SICUST, T.ILPROD
```

The problem was the duplicate lines in our tables from having multiple orders on the same invoice ID, from which I took the max value, then did a sum of those values after stripping out the date in the group by statement. Hope somebody else may find this useful!

Answer (score 0):

If you want know how many times your costumer by a single qty /price and want the  total value you can try something like this

```
 SELECT SIH.SICUST, SIL.ILPROD, date(SIL.ILDATE), SIL.ILNET, SIL.ILQTY,
    sum(SIL.ILQTY)*sum(SIL.ILNET) as TotalValue, count(*) as HowManyTimes,
    SIH.SICUST || ' ' ||  rtrim(SIL.ILPROD) || ' '
    FROM NWBAKERS.BPCSF.IIM IIM,
         NWBAKERS.BPCSF.SIH SIH,
         NWBAKERS.BPCSF.SIL SIL
    WHERE SIH.SIINVN = SIL.ILINVN
    AND IIM.IPROD = SIL.ILPROD
    AND ((date(SIL.ILDATE) between '02/01/2016' and '02/29/2016'))
    and SIL.ILWHS ='PR'
    and SIL.ILQTY > '0'
    and SIH.SICUST = '40634'
    and SIL.ILPROD = '81039'
    GROUP BY SIH.SICUST, SIL.ILPROD, SIL.ILDATE, SIL.ILQTY, SIL.ILNET
```

I didn't tried it sorry ..

Comment: Thank You, I can give it a try!